# OpenLayers v5 XYZ source is making 'wrong' requests

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to add a tilelayer to a map, but the zoom level and x/y coords are not matching up in the network request for some reason.

Here's my code for the layer:

```
new TileLayer({
  source: new XYZ({
    url: 'myserver.com/tms/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
})
```

In the browser's network tab, the request looks something like `myserver.com/tms/10/585/716.png` and the response is an empty png file.

However when I take that url and manually decrease the zoom by 1, so it becomes `myserver.com/tms/9/585/716.png` I get the correct tile as a response. This is consistent across all zoom levels.

For reference, the OSM source layer works perfectly fine:

```
new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM(),
})
```

I'm guessing this is an issue on my part since the server is technically serving the right tiles but other than that I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source has a non-standard grid where what is normally zoom level 0 is missing and consequently all other levels are offset by 1.  You will need to set a custom tile grid based on a standard XYZ grid but omitting the first resolution

```
import TileGrid from 'ol/tilegrid/TileGrid.js';
import {createXYZ} from 'ol/tilegrid.js';
import {get as getProjection} from 'ol/proj.js';


new TileLayer({
  source: new XYZ({
    url: 'myserver.com/tms/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png',
    tileGrid: new TileGrid({
      extent: getProjection('EPSG:3857').getExtent(),
      resolutions: createXYZ().getResolutions().slice(1)
    })
  })
})
```